# nginx in front of Rails

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, mtls

We want to put nginx with mTLS in front of our Rails app. We want that mTLS is turned on only if request goes trough specific domain. E.g.:

I want that `https://mypage.com` works without mTLS, however I want that `https://secure.mypage.com` works via mTLS.

Is it a good idea to run single server instance which uses `Procfile`:

```
web: sudo service nginx start 
rails: rails s -p 3000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think that the configuration of your origin server has anything to do with the protocols of the reverse proxy in front of it?

Just configure mypage.com and secure.mypage.com as different virtual hosts (with different configurations) in nginx. By default the server name will be passed through to the backend. If you want to pass on details of a client certificate, you can do that too. Or you can have more than one backend service implementing different functionality and point each vhost to a different backend.